# Error during siesta calculation

Tags: siesta

I am optimizing $\ce{NiCuWO4}$/$\textrm{g}\ce{C3N4}$ system but the calculation terminated showing the error SCF did not converge after the maximum number of steps. As per the suggestion given by Prof. Nick Papior in this site, I have played with the mixing weight. Initially, I kept mixing weight at 0.05 and then gradually decreased up to 0.005. Also, I have checked with 0.1.  Kindly suggest to me how to solve this issue. The input is given below for your reference.

```
 # System Descriptor
 SystemName Au-m-GGA
 SystemLabel   Au-m-GGA
 
 NumberOfAtoms                64
 NumberOfSpecies               6
 
 %block Chemical_Species_Label
 1      6     C
 2      7     N
 3      8     O
 4     28     Ni
 5     29     Cu
 6     74     W
 %endblock Chemical_Species_Label
 
 %block PAO.BasisSizes
C       DZP
N       DZP
O       DZP
Ni      DZP
Cu      DZP
W       DZP
 %endblock PAO.BasisSizes
 
 AtomicCoordinatesFormat Ang
 AtomicCoorFormatOut     Ang
 
 %block AtomicCoordinatesAndAtomicSpecies
      6.1181      0.2377      8.9015   1   C
     14.0667      0.2266      8.9379   1   C
      8.5620      0.2227      9.8949   2   N
     16.6416      0.2593      9.5216   2   N
      4.7633      0.2686      8.4995   2   N
     12.6415      0.2331      8.7549   2   N
      7.8646      1.3452      9.6715   1   C
     15.8991      1.3550      9.4135   1   C
      6.5377      1.3437      9.5268   2   N
     14.5631      1.3590      9.4256   2   N
      2.8185      1.4865      9.2632   2   N
     10.6990      1.4556      9.5692   2   N
      3.9955      1.4942      8.6207   1   C
     11.8798      1.4554      8.9112   1   C
      2.0582      2.5677      8.9699   1   C
      9.9427      2.5337      9.2359   1   C
      4.5645      2.5679      8.0819   2   N
     12.4332      2.5358      8.3880   2   N
      8.5324      2.5453      9.4850   2   N
     16.5545      2.5725      9.2130   2   N
      3.8523      3.6750      8.3137   1   C
     11.7238      3.6485      8.5906   1   C
      2.5330      3.6915      8.4518   2   N
     10.3940      3.6484      8.6732   2   N
      6.6399      3.7903      8.6184   2   N
     14.5366      3.7629      8.6102   2   N
      7.7725      3.7751      9.3234   1   C
     15.7790      3.7873      9.1163   1   C
      7.1860      3.4905     12.1308   3   O
     12.5170      3.4736     12.1603   3   O
     17.8287      3.3294     11.8556   3   O
      4.7235      3.4211     11.0232   3   O
     10.1279      3.6009     11.4827   3   O
     15.3016      3.5078     11.5531   3   O
      3.5314      4.0003     12.2647   6   W
      8.8020      4.1758     12.5571   6   W
     14.0880      4.0945     12.7350   6   W
      5.7370      2.1356     12.0801   5   Cu
     16.3440      2.1376     12.3887   5   Cu
      3.9125      1.1743     12.1378   3   O
      9.1847      1.3617     12.5343   3   O
     14.4883      1.2723     12.6153   3   O
      6.3382      1.0687     13.5843   3   O
     11.7842      1.0491     13.7621   3   O
     17.0620      0.8026     13.5558   3   O
      3.9419      3.5444     13.9598   3   O
      9.1980      3.7155     14.2521   3   O
     14.4497      3.6325     14.4455   3   O
      6.3955      3.4453     15.3869   3   O
     11.7086      3.4316     15.5716   3   O
     17.1209      3.2374     15.3809   3   O
      6.7890      0.6192     15.2771   6   W
     12.1170      0.6076     15.4809   6   W
     17.4962      0.4177     15.2683   6   W
      4.6283      2.4363     15.3917   5   Cu
     15.2799      2.3537     15.6275   5   Cu
      5.6302      1.2253     16.5228   3   O
     10.8726      1.2066     16.6388   3   O
     16.3371      1.0134     16.5152   3   O
      3.2299      1.0492     15.5874   3   O
      8.4222      1.2208     15.6806   3   O
     13.7330      1.2036     15.9717   3   O
      9.9109      2.4789     15.5498   4   Ni
     11.0499      2.1820     12.3846   4   Ni
 %endblock AtomicCoordinatesAndAtomicSpecies
 LatticeConstant    1.00 Ang
 
 %block LatticeVectors
     15.9064      0.0000      0.0000
     -0.2517      4.6287      0.0000
      4.1859     -0.3183     22.8650
 %endblock LatticeVectors
 %block kgrid_Monkhorst_Pack
 3   0   0 0.0
 0   3   0 0.0
 0   0   1 0.0
 %endblock kgrid_Monkhorst_Pack
 
 XC.functional           GGA
 XC.authors              PBE
 SpinPolarized           .true.
 MeshCutoff              300. Ry
 MaxSCFIterations        300
 DM.MixingWeight         0.05
 DM.Tolerance            5.d-5
 DM.NumberPulay          5
 SolutionMethod          diagon
 ElectronicTemperature   300 K
 MD.TypeOfRun            cg
 MD.VariableCell         .true.
 MD.NumCGsteps           800
 MD.MaxForceTol   0.01 eV/Ang

 WriteCoorInitial
 WriteCoorStep
 WriteCoorXmol           .true.
 WriteKpoints            .true.
 WriteEigenvalues        .true.
 WriteKbands             .true.
 WriteBands              .true.
 WriteMullikenPop        1
 WriteMDCoorXmol         .false.
 WriteMDhistory          .false.
 DM.UseSaveDM
 MD.UseSaveXV            .true.
 SaveRho
 SaveDeltaRho
 SaveElectrostaticPotential .true.
 WriteSiestaDim          .true.
```

Comment: +1 but please make note of the edits that I made. Hopefully others won't have to do that type of work on your questions next time. Since you mentioned Nick's suggestion, can you please  provide a URL link to it in your post?

Comment: Also, just increase max scf steps :)

Comment: Did you run convergence test?